# What is the difference between this two variables in Minecraft source code?

Tags: java, minecraft

I was having a look at 1.19 MCP, which I downloaded from their GitHub, when I found something strange. In the file `net.minecraft.world.damagesource`, the class `DamageSource` contains two variables, among others, that look exactly the same.

These are the declarations:

```
public static final DamageSource IN_FIRE = (new DamageSource("inFire")).bypassArmor().setIsFire();

public static final DamageSource ON_FIRE = (new DamageSource("onFire")).bypassArmor().setIsFire();
```

Does anyone know why both variables are very similar? What is the difference between them? Where is one used and where is the other one used?

I tried looking online and trying to follow the implementations of both variables, but so far no good.

Comment: My guess: One is when you're standing in fire, the other is when you've caught on fire. Most likely the damage handling is very similar in both cases, but they are still two different scenarios. I suspect it helps to differentiate for things like specific death messages and so on.

Comment: @Slaw Indeed, this at least is related to death messages. "<player> went up in flames" (in fire) vs "<player> burned to death" (on fire but not in fire). See also: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Death_messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the names, the one might be damage due to the player walking *in fire* and the other due to the player having caught fire, or in other words, being *on fire*.

As @Sweeper has pointed out in the comments, the distinction is required, for example, to give precise [death messages](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Death_messages).